# Octave equivalent of matlab's polyshape?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

The [polyshape function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.html) takes 2D vertices and generates a polygon that can be visualized/plotted. Is there an octave equivalent for this? Alternatively, what's the best way to plot polygons given the 2D vertices?

Comment: `plot`? `line`? `patch`? `fill`? Which way is "best" depends on your data and desired result.